# Como concatenar duas strings?

Tags: string, r, concatenação-de-string

Supondo que tenho duas strings, `Olá`  e `mundo!`, como eu as concateno usando R?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Através do comando `paste`:

```
paste("Olá", "mundo!", sep=" ")
[1] "Olá mundo!"

paste("Olá", "mundo!", sep="-")
[1] "Olá-mundo!"
```

Utilize o comando `?paste` para acessar o help da função e aprender suas outras particularidades.